# Characters like '»' and '✔' don't appear in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, unicode

When designing a web page, I found characters like '✔' cannot appear    at all in Firefox when they can in Chrome.

Example CSS code corresponding an input which type is 'check':

```
#todo-list li .toggle:after {
content: '✔';
/* 40 + a couple of pixels visual adjustment */
line-height: 43px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #d9d9d9;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #bfbfbf;
}
```

It works in Chrome just perfectly. Sorry I don't have enough credits to post images.
But when in Firefox, the character just doesn't come out, but display as a regular checkbox.
I HAVE set my charset as 'utf-8' in the html file.

Comment: The characters are showing here in Firefox (v31). Could it be a font problem? What font are you using in Chrome, what font in Firefox?

Comment: "As a regular checkbox"? So that means the character *does* appear, it just looks like a checkmark with a box instead of just a checkmark? An image would really help here. Upload it somewhere and post a link to it.

Comment: I'm viewing the post in Firefox 31 and I see the characters just fine.

Comment: It all depends upon the font.  Some fonts contain that checkmark character and some fonts do not.

Comment: What is the HTML element this is being applied to, and what other settings affect it? In particular, what is the font?

Answer (score 0):

> You will never make fonts look exactly the same in all browsers,
>   whether the characters in question are Dingbats or not.

That being said, not all browsers have the same font family, this specific character style called [Dingbat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat) will not be the same for all browsers. But you maybe able to escape this by changing the font family, eg. *font-family: Meiryo*, and as you may know this won't work for users that don't have the same font family as you do.

For further information, please read [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633443/unicode-special-characters-appear-differently-in-firefox-vs-chrome-ie)