# &#10006; is too small in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox renders special character too small. I compared in Chrome and Firefox. 
You can check - http://jsfiddle.net/y23rwucp/

How can I do same size in all browsers using `px`:

```
font-size: 14px;
```

Thank you

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WyMY.png)

P.S. I'm testing on Mac.

Comment: "Too small" compared to what? "Same size" as what?

Comment: The size seems good to me.

Comment: @showdev, same size in every browser. Google chrome and Firefox. Look the screenshot please

Comment: That's not how it look in my Firefox. IE and Chrome shows it smaller than Firefox. Dingbats just isn't very predictable.

Comment: @showdev, i don't use `pt`.

Comment: [This might be informative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633443/unicode-special-characters-appear-differently-in-firefox-vs-chrome-ie).

Comment: @showdev, thank you! Bad to hear that. I'll use icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, using dingbats (or any font not designed for this perpose) for this is not optimal. A proper replacement would be `&times;`:

```
span{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
<span>&times;</span>
```

You could also make a class and use the before. You can use this as simply
`<span class="Times"></span>` or put text in the span (required a tad more css)

```
.Times:before { 
    content:"\00d7";
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This might be worthy to add: [**Font Awesome**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) does the same thing I just did with the `:before`, only they have a lot of icons. If you need various icons in your site, you might want to check this out.

Comment: Working! What I need!